Is precognition incompatible with God?
Precognition is usually associated as a supernatural quality.
If precognition is true, then everything that follows from an event is determined by that event.
If everything is determined, do we have free will?
Is this a paradox? Can god exist if precognition is true?
If precognition is false, do we have free will?
If we have free will, does God exist?

What do you mean by "precognition"? In addition, please give an example of a real case, not a fictitious case. Thanks.

@JoWehler  I expected your rebuttle.

It's not a rebuttal, but a call for clarification.

@JoWehler I know de ja vue has had an attempt of an explanation. If I had, then the matter would be resolved, and not open to speculation .

If you mean precognition as in the "psychic" human ability to predict future events, then it doesn't necessarily follow that "everything" is determined by the current state of matter (it may instead just be some things, or this ability may exist outside of that). And it's not things being determined from "an event", unless you define "event" to be the current state of matter. And this isn't an "if and only if" - if precognition implies determinism, that doesn't mean determinism implies precognition (so precognition being false says nothing about determinism).

This is a black n white or false dilemma fallacy. As someone who has known more than one person with these abilities I can say: They can see and know more than us ordinary folks. And they can not know. And be wrong also! One super intuitive lady said to me: If God shows me the insides of people's minds and/or the future, it means He is allowing for a choice. If there is no choice, He doesn't show me.

@Rushi They know some things, they don't know other things. Sometimes they're right, sometimes they're wrong. Usually it's all very vague and easy to post-hoc rationalise to fit predictions to pretty much anything that happens. It's almost as if their precognition exists purely in their own head, as some combination of logical inference, guessing and imagination, without them having any special access to the future. We're still waiting for even just a single reliable demonstration of such abilities.

@NotThatGuy It's almost as if their precognition exists purely in their own head... Yes of course. All cognition has been "in the head" since Kant's Copernican revolution

beginner here. If you’re referring to the Christian God, I don’t think it contradicts. In Christianity, free-will doesn’t really seem to exist due to God being all knowing and seeing how everything plays out (“God’s plan”). In this perspective, I don’t think pre-cognition necessarily contradicts.

Your right if god had a plan then precognition would be a state of that plan. The Christian God as far as I know it is omniscient and omnipotent. These two concepts are incompatable. If god knows everything can his omnipotence change it? If God exists that god is just as vulnerable as we are.

@8Mad0Manc8 I agree with this. I tried to take a perspective to answer the question, but I do believe that God is contradictory in Christianity. Perhaps he is simply vain and likes to hype himself up rather than actually being what he and his writers claim. I always found that the only plausible answer.

I believe in a God that can reduce itself to its own creation and no more it's judgement is a self reflection. If it condemn man it condems itself as an equal.

Now your thinking a vain God contradicts a responsible God. I believe God is not black and white and distinguishes simply to absolute right and wrong. A God that does that is an asshole.@Gelatin
